# How to perform mysql asynchronous data synchronization?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replication

I wish to perform asynchronous data synchronization between two mysql databases kept on two servers without taking a mysql -dump of the whole database each time and also without locking the any of the databases during operation. Let's say we'have got a library management portal that adds and remove members. Our main database and server is situated remotely and can't be accessed without internet. I don't want my operations to be left discontinued for the time being (when there is no internet), I wish to store my data locally on some lan server and and when internet connectivity is found , i want automatic data synchronization and wish only the changes made to be transferred to the main database. How to do this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: just a direct connection to the main servers database...which is located remotely and hence it always requires an internet connection.

Comment: Setup a master slave: It is essentially synchronous unless you have no connection for a while. Then when the connection comes back up, it will re-synchronize

Comment: two things- first what do you mean by 'no connection for a while".. will it have a specific time limit and second.. can you provide me with the relevant links . some of the links which is saw were simply taking the whole mysql dump or were locking the database. I don't wish either.